# Division not outputting correct answer c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I'm trying to make a basic math program to get warmed up to the language.when I try to do the problem 9/2 or anything with a decimal the answer seems to be wrong. I would like an output of "4.50" but I keep on getting "4.00". What causes this and how do I prevent it. thanks

```
double INN = 0.0;   
INN = 9 / 2;
std::cout.precision (3);
std::cout << std::showpoint << INN << endl;
```

Comment: If you perform integer division, it ignores the factional part. Try `9.0 / 2.0`

Comment: @RSahu because it been definitely asked before and it's clearly explained in textbooks

Comment: @saikumar, If it's been asked before, the question should be voted to be closed as a duplicate. I am sure it's explained in textbooks but as are many other questions. That is not reason enough for downvoting.

Comment: This can be answered in the first 10 pages of any C/C++ introductory textboox or online tutorial.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer can be found in the first pages of any C/C++ textbook or online tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INN = 9 / 2;` will assign `4.0` to `INN`.

Replace it with `INN = 9.0 / 2.0;` to assign `4.5`.

---

Explanation:

Because both `9` and `2` are integers, `9 / 2` always results in an integer division, the result of which is an integer too. Thus the result must be rounded, and is rounded down to the nearest integer.

Whereas `9.0` and `2.0` are doubles, thus `9.0 / 2.0` will result in a floating point division, which results in a double value.

Comment: You don't explain why that occurs.

Comment: @NeilKirk Added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In the statement, `INN=9/2;` both 9 and 2 are integers, hence the overload of `/` operator which takes two integers is called and the result is an integer.

From the standard,

> When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the
>   algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.88) If the
>   quotient a/b is representable, the expression (a/b)*b + a%b shall
>   equal a.

This is often called truncation towards zero.

To actually call the floating point version of the `/` operator, you must cast atleast one of the operands to `double` or `float`.

`INN=(double)9/2;`

This will give you `4.5`.